How do i get list of applications deployed to a given WebLogic server instance
Given weblogic server instance managed_server01 i wish to get the list of application names deployed on it.
Note: managed_server01 is NOT RUNNING
The application may be deployed (targetted) to managed_server01 or to a Cluster of which managed_server01 is a member of.
I did take reference from :
WLST query (List deployed applications and hosts together)
It works when the server Instance is running. However, it does not work the the weblogic server instance is down:
root@remhost1:/web/bea_apps/domains/mydomain/servers/managed_server01# cat listapps.py
connect('wladmin', 'welcome123', 't3://remhost1:12000')
cd('AppDeployments')
deplymentsList=cmo.getAppDeployments()
for app in deplymentsList:
      domainConfig()
      cd ('/AppDeployments/'+app.getName()+'/Targets')
      mytargets = ls(returnMap='true')
      domainRuntime()
      cd('AppRuntimeStateRuntime')
      cd('AppRuntimeStateRuntime')
      for targetinst in mytargets:
            curstate4=cmo.getCurrentState(app.getName(),targetinst)
            print app.getApplicationName(), targetinst;
root@remhost1:/web/bea_apps/domains/mydomain/servers/managed_server01# java weblogic.WLST listapps.py  | grep managed_server01 | grep -v dr--

Thus, i need WLST script or some command line to list all applications taregtted to a given weblogic server instance or cluster which that instance is a part of.
Even, a solution like parsing the config.xml of weblogic to extract the information would be a great help.
Kindly suggest.
